# Object doesn't support property or method 'jqGrid' on windows server 2012

Tags: javascript, jquery

the jq grid is running fine on asp.net dev server but on IIS 8 (Windows Server 2012) it is giving the following error: Object doesn't support property or method 'jqGrid'

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#GridList').jqGrid({
            autoencode: true,
            autowidth: true,           
            caption: 'List',
            cmTemplate: { sortable: false },
            datatype: 'json',
            jsonReader: { 'repeatitems': false, 'id': 'Id' },
            emptyrecords: 'No record Found',
            multiselect: true,
            gridview: true,
            recordpos: 'left',
            height: '100%',
            loadui: 'block',
            pager: '#pager',
            rowList: [10, 15, 20, 50],
            rowNum: 10,
            viewsortcols: [true, 'vertical', true],
            shrinkToFit: true,
            url: '@Url.Action("List")',
            viewrecords: true,
            width: '650',
            colModel: [

                @Html.GetGridColumn(model => model.Id),
                @Html.GetGridColumn(model => model.ResultId),
                @Html.GetGridColumn(model => model.HostReference),
                @Html.GetGridColumn(model => model.FirstName),
                @Html.GetGridColumn(model => model.LastName),
                @Html.GetGridColumn(model => model.UserID)
            ]
        });
        //jQuery('#GridList').jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false });
        jQuery("#GridList").navGrid('#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });

        jQuery("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            var s;
            s = jQuery("#GridList").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');

            alert(s);
        });

    });
</script>
```

Update:

this is how i call the list:

protected ActionResult List(GridSettings grid)
        {
            var query = ListQuery.AsQueryable().OrderBy(grid.SortColumn, grid.SortOrder);

```
        if (grid.IsSearch && grid.Where != null && grid.Where.rules != null)
        {
            query = grid.Where.rules.Aggregate(query,
                                               (current, rule) => current.Where(rule.field, rule.data, rule.op));
        }           

        var count = query.Count();

        var data = query.Skip((grid.PageIndex - 1) * grid.PageSize)
                        .Take(grid.PageSize)
                        .Select(Mapper.Map<TModel, TListModel>);


        // TO DO: Prevent GridDataType.NoDisplay fields from being
        // serialised
        var result = new
        {
            total = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)count / grid.PageSize),
            page = grid.PageIndex,
            records = count,
            rows = data.ToArray()
        };

        var serialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serialiser.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        //serialiser.RegisterConverters(new[] { new SingleSelectConverter() });
        //serialiser.RegisterConverters(new[] { new MultiSelectConverter() });

        var jsonString = serialiser.Serialize(result);

        return new ContentResult { Content = jsonString, ContentType = "application/json"};            
    }
```

Comment: How are you including jqGrid plugin script on the page?

Comment: iam adding my bundles like this:

Comment: bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                   "~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js",
                   "~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.js",
                   "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

Answer (score 0):

What seems that you have issue of reference, just check the jqgrid library path whether that is referenced properly or not.

or may be you could have forgot to reference the library with all other required library.

---

#### some side notes:

Since you are using `dataType:"json"` and i can see that you have not used `loadonce: true` option in the list which is required when dataType is "json" and you have mentioned your column names, try including those too.:

```
jQuery('#GridList').jqGrid({
        autoencode: true,
        autowidth: true,           
        caption: 'List',
        cmTemplate: { sortable: false },
        datatype: 'json',
        ........
        loadonce: true
});
```

Comment: tried loadonce:true, with no luck, grid loads data when i run from visual studio, when i debug with firefox it displays jqgrid with columns, but no data, with error code 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found my answer, i was using third party dll, it's in dll folder, when i depolyed, i had to add to bin folder as well...Thank you for the help